# How to configure SublimeRepl to work with chicken scheme?

Tags: scheme, sublimetext2, read-eval-print-loop, chicken-scheme, sublimerepl

Is there anyone who is able to configure Sublime Text 2 and SublimeRepl to work with chicken scheme?

I've got chicken repl in Sublime, but it displays error messages from the chicken scheme only (probably from the stderr output of the csi process), but it doesn't display prompt nor evaluated values.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass "-:c" flag to csi. (I guessed it from [emacs plugin](http://code.call-cc.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=chicken-core.git;a=blob_plain;f=misc/chicken.el;hb=HEAD))

So, you have to edit a bit `SublimeREPL/config/Scheme/Main.sublime-menu`. In my case is in the path (I'm in osx):

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Scheme/Main.sublime-menu
```

The file looks like [Main.sublime-menu](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/blob/master/config/Scheme/Main.sublime-menu).

Now you have to edit how the shell is open for scheme. So, go to the line 24 (for osx) and change the line:

```
"osx": ["scheme"],
```

by:

```
"osx": ["csi", "-:c"],
```

If you are in linux or windows, the fix is the same but, you have to edit line 23 or 25.

If you don't use "-:c" flag you will experiment the problem that you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is completely correct, but it is kind of annoying. I forked SublimeREPL with the necessary changes to save others the trouble. You can clone it to your `Packages` directory and you're done.

https://github.com/mnewt/SublimeREPL